# Passport control location when travelling from Disneyland Resort (Marne-la-Vallée/Chessy) by train to London

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, france

I am an Indian planning to take a train from Disneyland Resort (Marne-la-Vallée/Chessy) to London. Please let me know where France and UK immigration respectively will be done.

Comment: You will change trains to the Eurostar in Paris, so it's the same as travelling from Paris to London.

Comment: No they won't change trains.  There is a direct train once a day between Marne-la-Vallée-Chessy and London St. Pancras. Immigration is performed at Marne-la-Vallée-Chessy station before departure.  This isn't a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 5):

If you are taking the direct train (daily during the Summer and other high-demand times, five times weekly the rest of the year) from Marne-la-Vallée-Chessy to London St. Pancras, then French Immigration Exit and UK Immigration entry are performed in Marne-la-Vallée-Chessy station - to be precise, in the upper concourse of that station.

Because the station only does this once a day, the queues can get pretty long. Eurostar generally recommend checking in an hour before departure, and I'd support them on that: they don't have the sorts of staff numbers that there are in Gare du Nord or St Pancras to process lots of passengers quickly.

Comment: The UK doesn't have border control at Marne-la-Vallée - it's done on arrival in the UK

Answer (score 1):

It'll be similar to flying: French immigration is performed at Marne la Vallée Chessy, while [UK Immigration takes place on arrival at St Pancras](https://help.eurostar.com/faq/be-en/question/Will-our-passports-be-checked-at-Marne-la-Vall%C3%A9e-station-Disneyland-Paris).

This is the only Eurostar route where UK immigration is not cleared in mainland Europe.